# Ajax - Reload Div after php form submit - Problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an `PHP` Page with Input field and `Form Action`.
After i submit the `form` i get the results on new Page.

Page reloading its not allowed because otherwise its generated new infos and safe it in Database (Makes an new `Post request`).

But now on the Seconds Page, after form submit, i want reload an `Div` class with `ajax`.

My Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("myx_function();",2000);      
    function myx_function(){
      $('#divrefreshone').load(location.href + ' #divrefreshcontent'); 
    return false;    
    }
  </script>
```

Div Content:

```
<div id="divrefreshone">  
<div id="divrefreshcontent">  

<?php 

if ($dbvalue == 0)
    {
        echo " <br><center>Wait for Status Update...</center><br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo " <br><center>Status = Complete</center><br>";
    }

?> 
</div>
</div>
```

The problem now is, I can't make an Ajax call, the div will be hidden after the 2 seconds and dont reload. I just want the status to be checked every few seconds from the database and show the new results.
When I check the call in the developer tools, it goes to the error page from the header:

```
if (!isset($_POST['myinput']))
{
    header("Location: /error");
    exit(1);
}
```

I have some `header("");` redirects in my Header, i have also tried it with `meta redirect` and `return false;`.
I'm trying to find a solution now for 5 hours, anyone an idea?